# What is a Line Terminator and how does it apply to comments?

Tags: java, comments, jls

I'm reading into the Java Language Specifications (se8), and I came across this..

```
Lines are terminated by the ASCII characters CR, or LF, or CR LF. The two characters CR immediately followed by LF are counted as one line terminator, not two.

A line terminator specifies the termination of the // form of a comment (§3.7).
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.4

I don't understand what it means, and there aren't any examples of how it works. Based off context, I'm guessing a line terminator would be the end of a comment, so for

```
/*
  *
  */
```

The line terminator would be `*/` (please correct me if I'm wrong)

I don't understand how line terminators would apply to `//` comments.

EDIT: So I guess I wasn't going crazy, `\n \r` are considered line terminators, which was my very first guess. What really confuses me is why they refer to comments when talking about this, when usually (from what Ive seen), they're used for Strings.

Comment: You're missing the fundamental purpose of the line terminator. The reference to comments isn't saying you have necessarily anything to be responsible for, only that the file encoding for your platform results in a source file that has lines terminated by the appropriate character. You can't see them (you only see a "new line"). The compiler parses your code and interprets the "line terminator" as one of CR, LF, or CRLF, and continues parsing your code. That's where the comment reference comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

It's the ASCII encoded character sequence that signifies the end of a line, depending on your platform.

For instance, ASCII characters CR (carriage return), LF (line feed), or both CRLF (Carriage Return, immediately followed by line feed) are used to denote the end of a line of text.
On most UNIX platforms, only a single CR character is used, while on DOS based platforms, usually the sequence CRLF is used to denote the end of line, and as such, that sequence is usually interpreted as "one terminator" because they must be in that order.

To address the specific question (based on comment feedback):
This has nothing to do with comments, from your perspective as the user. It matters to the parser of your Java source code, in that, when a line is read, it expects the appropriate line terminator to be there. You effectively accomplish this by pressing "Enter" to insert a new line. The encoding of the file, your text editor, and platform all need to be in agreement which specific character; CR, LF, or CRLF are actually inserted when you add a new line.

Comment: How does this apply to `//` comments? I understand `\n` and `\r`, but how does this apply to comments?

Comment: Every line has a line separator, no matter if comment, code or any other text.

Comment: It doesn't apply to comments at all, from your perspective. You pressing the "Enter key" when you finish a comment inserts the appropriate invisible character, terminating the line. The code parser uses this to determine if the line is properly terminated.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies, Ryan. So it really has nothing to do with comments? Other than being handled behind the scenes?

Comment: What this passage is trying to explain is that when a comment starts with `//`, it ends at the line terminator and does not carry over to the next line the way the `/*` comment does. In other words, `//` is the start of a one-line comment (which can be placed after a line of executed code).

Answer (score 2):

A line terminator is an actual ascii character which is **invisible to humans** but important to computers. The line terminator character tells the computer where to start a new line. We tell computers to "print" terminators when we want new lines. 
For example, in java, instead of doing

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

You could do

```
System.out.print("Hello World\n");
```

Where the "\n" represents the line terminator or "new line".